# Delete Account Attachments where file format is JPEG, PNG using Trigger

Tags: trigger, attachment

I want to delete attachments on account where file format is JPEG or PNG using trigger. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a preface, see [Comparison Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) for more depth on how `LIKE` and `IN` work.

You can query against `ContentType` as follows:

```
SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ContentType IN ('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png')
```

I am not sure what other formats `ContentType` takes on, so you could fuzzy search as follows:

```
SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ContentType LIKE ('%jpeg', '%jpg', '%png')
```

From there, deleting the results should be straightforward.

```
public static void deleteImages(List<Account> newRecords)
{
    delete [
        SELECT Id FROM Attachment
        WHERE ParentId IN :newRecords
        AND ContentType IN ('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png')
    ];
}
```